# Difference between two way of promise chain implementation

Tags: javascript, promise

I noticed two way of promise chain: Is there any differences ?

```
promise1()   
  .then(promise2)
  .then(promise3)
  .then(promise4);
```

and

```
promise1().then(function() {
     return promise2();
   }).then(function() {
     return promise3();
   }).then(function() {
     return promise4(){
   }).then(function() {
   });
```

Comment: `function() { return x() }` is  the same as `x`

Comment: you have not invodked in the first set of promises

Comment: assuming that your promise functions do not need any arguments to produce the promise that you need they are the same with the exception of the second being ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference - `then` calls its argument with the result value, but your second snippet ignores any paramters and calls all function with zero arguments. Also it is guaranteed to fulfill with `undefined` (if it doesn't reject) because of the additional empty callback, in contrast to the first snippet that resolves with the return value of `promise4(…)`.

And of course, the first one is also a lot easier to read.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/zehuzihelu/edit?html,js,output    Does this JavaScript code represent what you are talking about. First promise chain will log right result in console, but second one will log undefined.

Comment: @Milos yes, exactly

Comment: Maybe you should expand your answer with code example, it would be clearer for people who do not read comments :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no difference in both of your snippets in terms of sequence, as your code will be run in a same sequence in both of your snippet.

But there is couple of differences which your snippets are showing. One of which is passing of arguments and second one is of returning the then result.

Considering the first difference, the first snippet takes the arguments although you are not using it, which is not the case in the second snippet as you are not passing any argument nor using it.

Lastly while considering the second difference you are not returning any thing from then in first snippet whereas in second snippet you are calling function against the return statement from each then except of last then, which results in returing the undefined in the end.